# Why does my function always return true after test connexion

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem, this function "testofconnct" which tests the connection always returns true even when I disconnect from the internet on my pc

```
class testconnexion {
     fun testofconnct(context: Context): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val nw = connectivityManager.activeNetwork?: return false
            val actNw = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(nw) ?: return false
            return when {
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
                //for other device how are able to connect with Ethernet
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
                //for check internet over Bluetooth
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_BLUETOOTH) -> true
                else -> false
            }
        } else {
            return connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo?.isConnected ?: false
        }
    }
```

also "activeNetworkInfo" and "isConnected" is crossed out, if I click on these two words I have: :

'getter for activeNetworkInfo: NetworkInfo?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
'getter for isConnected: Boolean' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

An idea of the problem ?
Thank you

Comment: Are you testing on an emulator and disconnecting your pc's wifi? It's possible that the emulator itself still "has a connection" (it can talk to your pc for network traffic) and doesn't have any idea about the pc's network status.

Comment: yes i have tested, my pc is disconnected

Comment: The question is not whether your PC has an internet connection or not. The question is whether the **emulator** has an internet connection. The emulator likely believes that it _does_ have a connection, as it is set up to talk to your PC. The fact that your PC does not have an internet connection is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

this is the most basic connection test you can do without deprecated methods

```
object Connection {
    val isConnected = MutableStateFlow(false)

    fun initialize(context: Context) {
        val cm = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val request = NetworkRequest.Builder().build()
        val callback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onAvailable(network: android.net.Network) {
                isConnected.value = true
            }

            override fun onLost(network: android.net.Network) {
                isConnected.value = false
            }
        }
        cm.registerNetworkCallback(request, callback)
    }

}
```

you should initialize it one time and then you can call `Connection.isConnected.value` to get a sync result or `Connection.isConnected.collect{ }` to add a callback

Comment: Unresolved reference: MutableStateFlow
Call requires API level 21 (current min is 16): android.net.NetworkRequest.Builder()
Call requires API level 21 (current min is 16):android.net.NetworkRequest.Builder#build

Comment: sorry, I didn't know that your min API level was so low. Most apps set the min API level to 21

Comment: and : Unresolved reference: MutableStateFlow ?

Comment: it is included in the latest version of kotlin. Otherwise you can add the dependency `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2"`

Comment: unfortunately your code does not solve my problem because of the Unresolved reference: MutableStateFlow Call requires API level 21 (current min is 16): android.net.NetworkRequest.Builder() Call requires API level 21 (current min is 16)

Comment: Why not upgrade your kotlin version and min API level? Set `ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.21"` in the project gradle file  and `minSdkVersion 21` in the app gradle file